# How to know form of plotted Bézier function

Tags: polynomials, splines

Simple scenario is to see the Bézier function, but how to know which polynomial approximate it?

```
pts = {{0, -1}, {1, 0}, {2, -1}};
Graphics[{BezierCurve[pts], Green, Line[pts], Red, Point[pts]}]
```

Answer (score 9):

[Bézier Curves](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BezierCurve.html) have a standard formula:

```
bezier[pts_List] := With[{n = Length[pts] - 1},
  Evaluate @ Sum[Binomial[n, i] (1 - #)^(n - i) #^i pts[[i + 1]], {i, 0, n}] &]
```

In *Mathematica*, the coefficient function of `pts[[i + 1]]` is the same as `BernsteinBasis[n, i, #]`.

The above formula is of degree one less than the number of points in `pts`.  In the *Mathematica* function, the degree used in `BezierCurve` is typically limited to be at most the setting of `SplineDegree`.  By default, the setting is `Automatic`, and experimentation shows that it is the same as `SplineDegree -> 3`.  In this case the list of points are partitioned into overlapping groups of 4 (or less).

*Example.*  I added some more points, to show what happens when there is not a multiple of 4.

```
pts = {{0, -1}, {1, 0}, {2, -1}, {1, -1}, {2, 1}};    

g1 = Graphics[{Green, Line[pts], Black, BezierCurve[pts], Red, 
    Point[pts]}, Frame -> True];
g2 = ParametricPlot[
      Evaluate[bezier[#][t] & /@ Partition[pts, 4, 3, 1, {}]],
      {t, 0, 1},
      AspectRatio -> Automatic, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
      Prolog -> {Green, Line[pts], Red, Point[pts]}];

GraphicsRow[{g1, g2}]
bezier[#][t] & /@ Partition[pts, 4, 3, 1, {}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
(* {{3 (1 - t)^2 t + 6 (1 - t) t^2 + t^3,  -(1 - t)^3 - 3 (1 - t) t^2 - t^3},
    {1 + t,  -1 + 2 t}} *)
```

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case since you supplied three points you get a quadratic bezier:

```
t^2 pts[[1]] + 2  t (1 - t) pts[[2]] +  (1 - t)^2 pts[[3]]
```

You can see that this is correct at least to machine precision:

```
With[{t = RandomReal[{0, 1}]},
       t^2 pts[[3]] + 2  t (1 - t) pts[[2]] +  (1 - t)^2 pts[[1]] == 
              BezierFunction[pts][t]]
```

(* true *)

Assuming that BezierCurve is based on  BezierFunction of course..

Of course the real question is how the divine this automatically, that I dont know..