# Re-parameterizing sections of a Bézier curve into normal Cartesian functions

Tags: equation-solving, splines, intersection

I have a table:

```
    {{0., 0., 0.}, {0.002, 0.08942, -0.08942}, {0.008, 
  0.233889, -0.178706}, {0.018, 0.366918, -0.267724}, {0.031, 
  0.496136, -0.350769}, {0.049, 0.639568, -0.439999}, {0.07, 
  0.779356, -0.5245}, {0.095, 0.922931, -0.609077}, {0.124, 
  1.06945, -0.693271}, {0.156, 1.21404, -0.77438}, {0.191, 
  1.35745, -0.852947}, {0.229, 1.50013, -0.929279}, {0.271, 
  1.64566, -1.00987}}
```

where first column is the x axis, second column is top displacement and third column is bottom displacement. Using this table I can draw a `BezierCurve`.
Now what I would need is value (top and bottom displacement - actually the difference) at given value x.

For example I want to know f(x=0.08) for top and bottom displacement which is a Bézier curve.

I have thought about how to do this. And one idea is of course find the two intersection points of a Bézier curve and vertical line at given x. OR I wanted to multiply the Bézier curve with `KroneckerDelta`, assuming it would return me the right value, but it doesn't work as I had imagined.

So, any ideas are highly appreciated.

EDIT: Here is the code:

```
data = {{0., 0., 0.}, {0.002, 0.08942, -0.08942}, {0.008, 
  0.233889, -0.178706}, {0.018, 0.366918, -0.267724}, {0.031, 
  0.496136, -0.350769}, {0.049, 0.639568, -0.439999}, {0.07, 
  0.779356, -0.5245}, {0.095, 0.922931, -0.609077}, {0.124, 
  1.06945, -0.693271}, {0.156, 1.21404, -0.77438}, {0.191, 
  1.35745, -0.852947}, {0.229, 1.50013, -0.929279}, {0.271, 
  1.64566, -1.00987}, {0.315, 1.78733, -1.08524}, {0.363, 
  1.93174, -1.16256}, {0.412, 2.0702, -1.23705}, {0.464, 
  2.20889, -1.31193}, {0.518, 2.3453, -1.38579}, {0.574, 
  2.47975, -1.45874}, {0.632, 2.6125, -1.53086}, {0.691, 
  2.74158, -1.60107}, {0.751, 2.86742, -1.66957}, {0.813, 
  2.99234, -1.73757}}
 Graphics[BezierCurve[{Transpose[{data[[All, 1]], data[[All, 3]]}], 
    Transpose[{data[[All, 1]], data[[All, 2]]}]}], Axes -> True]
```

I assume this answers all the questions about what the input data means. Now to explain what I want. Let's consider the last two elements in the table

```
{0.751, 2.86742, -1.66957}
```

and

```
{0.813,  2.99234, -1.73757}
```

What I want is the y value that Bézier curve takes IF `0.715 < x <0.813` . For both - top and bottom Bézier Curve. I hope this makes things a bit more clear. And of course I picked this range randomly - I want this to work for any `x`.

Comment: What are/is the  _"value  (top and bottom displacement - actually the difference)"_?

Comment: So you actually have *two* Bézier curves in there?

Comment: @belisarius: Difference of y coordinate of the intersection points of the two Bezier curves at a given x.

Comment: @Guess who it is.: Two curves yes. One at the bottom (negative y if you wish) and one at the top (positive y, as seen from the table).

Comment: Bézier curves take *control points* as input, so they won't pass through the points you've given. Rather, your points will be the convex hull of the resulting curves.

Comment: I think you didn't understand me, due to my poor knowledge of English language.
Here is a picture of my Bezier curves: http://www4.slikomat.com/13/0713/9g3-Captur.png and as you said, BEzier cruve takes control points as input. Let's consider an example. If I had point T1= (1,1) and point T2=(5,2) than in this simple case the bezier curve is just a line connecting the two points. But my problem is: I want to get the y of Bezier cruve value at x=3.5, so between those two control points. I hope this is more understandable now.

Comment: Please make it clear. Do the 2nd and 3rd coordinates of your data points represent the ordinates of control points for the curves or the ordinates of actual points on the curves you want to generate?

Comment: Your problem isn't with English, but with not giving us the code you used to generate the Bezier curve you refer to. Please post your code.

Comment: I have eddited the original post, please check and let me know if it is not clear what my problem is.

Comment: So, using the notation of my answer, you want the functions represented by `BezierFunction[top]` and `BezierFunction[btm]` reparametertized to Cartesian `x`? I think it can be done, but I wouldn't put in the time to work it out unless you confirm my new reading of your question. Don't want to waste more time thanI already have.

Comment: @m_goldberg : Exactly!

Comment: Your title no longer describes your question. You are asking how to re-parameterize the function representing a special kind of Bezier curve into a normal single-valued function of the first coordinate of the curve points. I am taking the liberty of completely rewriting the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `bezier` from my answer to [How to know form of plotted Bézier function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29633/how-to-know-form-of-plotted-bezier-function/29659#29659) to get the formulas:

```
bezier[pts_List] := 
 With[{n = Length[pts] - 1}, 
  Evaluate@ Sum[Binomial[n, i] (1 - #)^(n - i) #^i pts[[i + 1]], {i, 0, n}] &]
```

Following the explanation in the linked answer, we can solve the equation `bezier[pp][t] == {x, y}` for `y` in terms of `x` as follows:

```
yfn[pts_] := Piecewise[
  Function[pp,
    Select[
      y /. N@ Solve[
          Rationalize[bezier[pp][t] == {x, y} && pp[[1, 1]] <= x <= pp[[-1, 1]], 0],
          {y}, {t}, Reals, Method -> Reduce] /. 
        Less -> LessEqual // Expand,
      Chop[# - pp[[1, 2]] /. x -> pp[[1, 1]]] == 0 &] /.
     ConditionalExpression -> Sequence] /@
   (If[Length@ Last@ # == 1, Most@ #, #] &@ Partition[pts, 4, 3, 1, {}]),
  Indeterminate]
```

(I used `Rationalize` and `N`, because that's what `Solve` would do, except `Solve` would issue warning messages about it.)

```
{y1, y2} = yfn /@ {Transpose[{data[[All, 1]], data[[All, 3]]}], 
    Transpose[{data[[All, 1]], data[[All, 2]]}]};
```

(The equations are somewhat long and complicated, as you might expect from plugging in the solution to a cubic polynomial into another cubic polynomial.)

```
Plot[{y1, y2}, {x, 0, Max@data[[All, 1]]}, Exclusions -> None]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

*Update notice:*
The original code for `yfn` had two weaknesses. (1) `Equal` on approximate numeric data sometimes returns `False` for numbers close to zero which differ only because of round-off error.  `Chop` was added to address this.  (It has a tolerance that can be adjusted depending on the magnitudes of the numbers in the data.)  (2) The `Partition` call on a list of length $3n+1$ results in a singleton list at the end that should be deleted.  For example,

```
Partition[Range[7], 4, 3, 1, {}]
(*  {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {4, 5, 6, 7}, {7}}  *)
```

Comment: I am trying to work with your code. But, somehow it doesn't work and since this is way beyond my knowledge of mathematica, I have to admit that I don't understand why. Here is my [printscreen](http://www4.slikomat.com/13/0723/y6u-Captur.png) also one more question, what is `pp` supposed to be?

Comment: @skrat `pp` is the argument of `Function`.  it represents each group of four points created by `Partition` (points 1,2,3,4, then 4,5,6,7, then 7,8,9,10, and so forth).  What version of Mathematica are you using?  I suspect that `Solve` is returning results in a different form than mine.  (I checked: the above code and it works for me on V10.1.)

Comment: Hmm, I am using 10.0.0.0.

Comment: Ok, I have updated to V10.1 and it works for the data I provided in OP, however this is not the full `data` I have. The original `data` I have has more than 1000 points - and of course I didn't copy all 1000 points here. Your approach works really well for the small amount of points, but as soon as I try to do it on 1000 points I get that error I talked about in my first comment. I can send you the whole file if you are interested, just let me know where and how.

Comment: @skrat Can you post the file to pastebin or DropBox?  Or would `data = Table[{t^2, t, -t}, {t, 0., 1., 1/1000}]` reproduce the problem?

Comment: Here is the [dropbox link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6qvwablkdnefkrj/sh94k4_cfdf.sh?dl=0)

Comment: @skrat  See if it works now.  It's a little slow to solve 1000 cubic equations.  I don't see an easy way around it, if you want exact solutions.  For a quick approximation, you could just interpolate: `y1 = Interpolation@Transpose[{data[[All, 1]], data[[All, 3]]}]; y2 = Interpolation@Transpose[{data[[All, 1]], data[[All, 2]]}]`.

Comment: This looks absolutely fantastic! Thank you Michael, thank you a lot! I would have one last, really simple, question though: Why doesn't `N[y1[60]]` (or any other number between 0 and 100) return a numerical result?

Comment: @skrat `Piecewise` constructs an expression that is not a function.  So you have to evaluate it with `N[y1 /. x -> 60]` or `Block[{x = 60}, N[y1]]`.

Comment: So I changed the code a bit. From `{y1, y2} = yfn /@ {Transpose[{data[[All, 1]], data[[All, 3]]}], 
    Transpose[{data[[All, 1]], data[[All, 2]]}]};` to (just added a factor to the coordinates) `{y1, y2} = yfn /@ {0.026*Transpose[{data[[All, 1]], data[[All, 3]]}], 
    0.026*Transpose[{data[[All, 1]], data[[All, 2]]}]};` . Than I tried it again and I got the same problem is in first comment to this answer. Following your solution I thought that updating `Chop` to `Chop[# - pp[[1, 2]] /. x -> pp[[1, 1]], 10^(-15)] == 0 &]` would do the job, but it doesn't. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

#### Edit

Based on the latest info from the OP, I offer up the following way to derive a Cartesian function from a suitable Bezier curve using [`BezierFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BezierFunction.html).

```
ctrlPts = {
  {0., 0., 0.}, {0.002, 0.08942, -0.08942}, {0.008, 0.233889, -0.178706}, 
  {0.018, 0.366918, -0.267724}, {0.031, 0.496136, -0.350769}, 
  {0.049, 0.639568, -0.439999}, {0.07, 0.779356, -0.5245}, 
  {0.095, 0.922931, -0.609077}, {0.124, 1.06945, -0.693271}, 
  {0.156, 1.21404, -0.77438}, {0.191, 1.35745, -0.852947}, 
  {0.229, 1.50013, -0.929279}, {0.271, 1.64566, -1.00987}
};

topCtrlPts = ctrlPts[[All, {1, 2}]]; 
btmCtrlPts = ctrlPts[[All, {1, 3}]]; 
topBPts = Table[BezierFunction[topCtrlPts][s], {s, 0., 1., .01}];
btmBPts = Table[BezierFunction[btmCtrlPts][s], {s, 0., 1., .01}];
topF = Interpolation[topBPts];
btmF = Interpolation[btmBPts];

With[{domain = {x, Sequence @@ (topF["Domain"][[1]])}}, 
  Plot[{topF[x], btmF[x]}, domain]]
```

[image: curves]