# Don't understand an evaluation with BezierFunction

Tags: equation-solving, evaluation

I don't understand the source of the failure of the following attempts to solve an equation involving the following very simple BezierFunction.

```
f = BezierFunction[{{0, 0}, {0, 0.8}, {1, 1}}];
```

The following three approaches fail, but in what I find to be a very odd way: the returned solution is 0.5, with no warning.

```
Solve[0.5 == Last[f[x]], x]
NSolve[0.5 == Last[f[x]], x]
Reduce[0.5 == Last[f[x]], x]
```

The following approach is successful (but produces a warning):

```
FindRoot[0.5 == f[x][[2]], {x, 0.5}]
```

To see what I find mysterious, consider the following trace.

```
Trace@NSolve[0.5 == Last[f[x]], x]
```

In particular, I would like to understand why `Last[BezierFunction[{{0, 0}, {0, 0.8}, {1, 1}}][x]]` evaluates to `x` within this trace. This is certainly not the behavior we get from ordinary functions (thank goodness):

```
h = t |-> {t + 1, t + 2};
Last[h[x]]  (* x+2 *)
```

Instead, it behaves like an undefined symbol:

```
Clear[h]
Last[h[x]]  (* x *)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Mathematica, [*everything is an expression*](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Expressions.html). When you use [`First`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/First.html) or [`Last`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Last.html) (which are just shortcuts to [`Part`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html)), you extract a part of your expression. For example:

```
Clear[g, x, y, z];

g[x] // Last
(* x *)

Part[g[x], -1]
(* x *)

g[x, y, z] // First
(* x *)

g[x, y, z] // Last
(* z *)
```

In your case, you have the following expression:

```
expr = BezierFunction[{{0, 0}, {0, 0.8}, {1, 1}}][x];
expr // Last
(* x *)
```

Is there something weird going on? No. You wanted to get the last part of your expression. Why does it look different if you use an "ordinary" function?

```
Last[(t |-> {t + 1, t + 2})[3]]
(* 5 *)
```

It is because this function will *get evaluated* when you give it a symbolic argument `x`! But the `BezierFunction` will stay *unevaluated* when you give it a symbolic argument. It will evaluate only if you give it a *numerical* argument.

```
BezierFunction[{{0, 0}, {0, 0.8}, {1, 1}}][x]
(* BezierFunction[{{0, 0}, {0, 0.8}, {1, 1}}][x] *)

BezierFunction[{{0, 0}, {0, 0.8}, {1, 1}}][.5] 
(* {0.25, 0.65} *)

BezierFunction[{{0, 0}, {0, 0.8}, {1, 1}}][.5] // Last
(* 0.65 *)
```

If you want to use it in `Solve`, you have to prevent `Last` acting on the expression too soon (that is: before the numerical argument is passed to the function). For example, you can do the following:

```
bf = BezierFunction[{{0, 0}, {0, 0.8}, {1, 1}}];
f[x_?NumericQ] := Last[bf[x]]

Solve[0.5 == f[x], x]
(* {{x -> 0.361508}} *)
```

Comment: That very last bit is helpful, but I am left with three questions. i. Is it documented that it will not evaluate a symbolic argument? ii. Why not evaluate symbolically e.g. to polynomials?  iii. How does this help me understand why `FindRoot[0.5 == Last[f[x]], {x, 0.5}]` fails but `FindRoot[0.5 == f[x][[2]], {x, 0.5}]` succeeds? Thanks!

Comment: @Alan i. AFAIK it's not documented, so are `InterpolatingFunction`, `BSplineFunction`, etc. ii. I'd say this design is convenient, because `BezierFunction` is mainly for numeric purpose, and nobody want to see a horrible large polynomial as the output in most cases. Also, according to [the wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Polynomial_form), the polynomial form of Bézier curve is not numerically stable. If you do want a polynomial, check this: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29633/1871 iii. As documented: `Last[expr]` is equivalent to `expr[[-1]]`.

Comment: @xzczd Yes of course. But I think your point is, `Last` will be applied to the unevaluated expression, while in contrast the entire expression `Part[f[x],2]` must remain 'unevaluated' and so subsequently becomes useful. That raises the question, why doesn't `NSolve[0.5 == f[x][[2]], x]` work, and there the answer is apparently: because the solution strategy tries to invert `f` instead of inverting `x|->f[x][[2]]` (or using another strategy entirely).

Comment: @Alan, the error message will tell you why `FindRoot[0.5 == f[x][[2]], {x, 0.5}]` "works" and `FindRoot[0.5 == Last[f[x]], {x, 0.5}]` doesn't. There is no second part of `f[x]`, and it will therefore stay in this "unevaluated" form `f[x][[2]]`. However, there _is_ the last part of `f[x]`, so it will immediately evaluate to `x` before solving.

Comment: @Domen Yes, see my previous comment.

Answer (score 3):

```
f = BezierFunction[{{0, 0}, {0, 0.8}, {1, 1}}];
FindRoot[0.5 == Indexed[f[x], 2], {x, 0.5}]
```

> `{x -> 0.361508}`

Or

```
FindRoot[0.5 == Last[f[x]], {x, 0.5}, Evaluated -> False]
```

> `{x -> 0.361508}`

Comment: `FindRoot` was already working, but this nicely gets rid of the warning. I especially like the clever use of `Indexed`. But is there a way to make say `NSolve` work?